# Active Directory user logon/logoff history in domain controller

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can  get Active Directory users logon/logoff history included also workstation lock/unlock.

Where keeps such kind of information?

Comment: Are you looking at monitoring users, or getting their full history?

Comment: I need to get AD users logon/logoff (userName,Loged/LogoffTime) information and insert to my db

Comment: Active Directory doesn't contain that information. If you want to know if the user logged in to a particular computer then you need to read the event logs.

Comment: Can I read server security log and get each computer/user log in/ log out history in domain?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There're probably other ways of getting that info...

Comment: I'm trying to get domain controlers Active Directory users login/log out time

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have enabled login/logoff events in each machine and they get send to domain controller *(via group policy...)*, you can read the event logs to get the information you're looking for.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ReadEventLogs
{
  class Program
  {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Security", ".");

        foreach(EventLogEntry entry in eventLog1.Entries)
        {
          //Event ID 4624 LOGON
          //EVent ID 4634 LOGOFF
          if (entry.InstanceId == 4634)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

`entry.` will contain the information you're looking for.

If no computer name or server is specified the event logs will be read from local machine `"."`.

Now having said that, there's an alternate solution to get the information you're looking for.

You can write a simple program that directly inserts the username (or any other information you need) directly to the database.

Once the user logins to any computer you can grab the username and call a stored procedure to insert the data in database.

```
...     
public static void LogUserDetail()
{
   //Get current logged on username
   string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
   using (SqlConnection conn = DBUtility.Connection)
   {
      using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
      {
         cmd.CommandText = "LogUserDetail";
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UserName", userName));
         cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DateTime", DateTime.Now));
         conn.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
 }
```

You would need to create a procedure `LogUserDetail` in database and create a `DBUtility` class with your connection.

You can then run this application as a `Group Policy` and every time somebody logs in to any computer on the network you will get the data in database.

Comment: how to get client ip address for AD login/logoff?

Comment: @MayankModi, please ask a new question.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960741/get-list-of-current-logged-in-users-in-active-directory