# Get list of current logged in users in Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to get list of current logged in users from Active Directory domain controller.

I'm able to get list of all users by using following code but not able to get current logged in users list.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.net")) {
   using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context))){
      List<UserPrincipal> users = searcher.FindAll().Select(u => (UserPrincipal)u).ToList();
      foreach (var u in users) {
           Resonse.Write(u.Name);
           Response.Write(u.LastLogon);
      }
   }
}
```

Is it possible using AD? If we can achieve with any alternate ways than also I'm open. I just need current logged in users list of AD domain users.

Thanks!

Comment: As StphenP said in his answer, AD doesn't have that info. However, you can read the `EventLogs` and capture that data from there.  `EventLog myLog = new EventLog("provider","machine name"); var entryCollection = myLog.Entries;`

Answer (score 3):

AD doesn't support it. You may be able to pull the info from the Event Logs on the DC's if you have auditing on. I've also seen people use a logon script to write a value into the extensionAttributes of the AD account. The other option is to reach out to each computer and query the currently logged on user for each of them.

Comment: +1 The real thing preventing this is that AD doesn't keep track of "logouts", so the best you could ever get is a list of users who recently logged in. On top of that, every time the user authenticates to anything, it counts as a login: access a shared folder? That's a login. Authenticate to an intranet site? That's a login.

Comment: I completely agree, the only real way to do it is to enumerate all sessions on each computer.